# WebBrowser control IE 10 documents standards mode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have a Windows Form C# application which hosts a WebBrowserControl in it. Application's users will have IE 11 installed on their machine. I need to force them to use IE 10 documents standards mode. I know I can do that by using FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION as described in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation

The issue is that I am able to force the users to IE10 using 10001 and/or 10000 registry values. But, my documents mode is not setting properly. I need to set it to document standards mode.

I have checked and registry values are getting set correctly. I am not sure what can be done at this point. Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Thanks,
Harit

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use code 10001 to force IE 10 all the time regardless of the doctype.

Are you certain you are setting the Correct Reg Key value based on the system type?  The key is in two different locations for a 32 or 64 bit system.  Double check that and the 10001 code is used.

Other than that according to the documentation it should always no matter what show in IE 10 mode.

G

Comment: One other thing to remember.  If you are running in debug and not seeing it render correctly, check after you have published to your environment.  If it renders correctly in your environment, but not while debug you need to add an additional registry key to wrap your debugger in the Standard you want.  ie yourapp.vshost.exe

Comment: Thanks for the response. All the machines are 64 bit and I have the registry set at SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION with a DOWRD value = 10001

Comment: Also, I am already using myApplication.exe and myApplication.vshost.exe in registry keys. Thanks for pointing that out though. :)

Comment: Are you using old or 3rd party controls that would force compatibility mode?  Some do this.  Are you using some browser specific CSS hacks?  Those can throw the doctype off.  Are you able to control the doctype and set the doctype to html standards on the pages renderred in the control?  If you use the standard IE 10 doctype like so and still getting compatibility mode?(<!DOCTYPE html> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">)

Comment: I am not using any third party controls or any other CSS hack(s). What I do is, I go to a URL which upon loading runs some YUI tests. Once the tests are done, they post the results to a server. 

The issue is that some of test fails when I launch them from my application. But, if I launch the same tests in Internet Explorer, they pass. 

If I add the URL to the list of 'Compatible' sites in IE, the test start failing, even from IE. My reasoning is, my application's webBrowser control is not running in standard document mode. Do you think its a correct assumption?

Comment: Well YUI is a third party code you are linking into.  I would not make that assumption, becasue it is intermittent.  If all tests passsed or failed through the control, then it could be that simple but some passing and some failing it is a deeper issue.  I would use Fiddler to see the doc modes of the request/responses.  In looking through the YUI forums again there are issues spanning IE 7 and 8.  I would test a blank page renderred by your control and see if that is in the correct mode.

Answer (score 0):

Next steps:  :-)
Are you using older or 3rd party controls that would force compatibility mode? Some do this with IE specific API's prior to IE8.

Are you using some browser specific CSS hacks? Those can throw the doctype off.

Are you able to control the doctype and set the doctype to html standards on the pages renderred in the control? If you use the standard IE 10 doctype like so and still getting compatibility mode?(  )

Since it is a control I assume you have no conditional comments, those can throw it off too, so if you code does have IE conditional comments in them that can hose the doctype.

If so then something else is FORCING the browser into compatibility mode.  I would start removing 3rd party controls, or CSS files, or even included Javascript files until you get the proper doctype and isolate the exact issue putting the doctype in the wrong mode.

You can test by rendering a straight html, with doctype set properly, sample page from your exe with no external links or 3rd party controls, just text on the page.  Does that render properly?

Just some hints to isolate the offending thing.